# Teclado solo mueva el EditText al aparecer

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

desarrollando mi app me he encontrado con el problema de que me gustaría que una vez que aparezca el teclado, no mueva ningún elemento, tan solo el EditText que lo invoca para ponerlo justo encima del teclado (como viene siendo lo normal).

El problema con el que me encuentro, es que si utilizo las etiquetas:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

o

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

El teclado al aparecer sigue moviendo todos los elementos, tan solo con la etiqueta:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

He conseguido que no se mueva nada, pero el EditText no se mueve a la parte superior del teclado, por lo que es imposible saber que es lo que se esta escribiendo.

Aporto unas imagenes comparativas con como lo hace Whatsapp, que es el resultado que quiero obtener y mi app con la etiqueta adjusPan:

Resultado que quiero obtener:
[image: Resultado que quiero obtener]

Mi app antes de desplegar el teclado:
[image: Mi app antes de desplegar el teclado]

Resultado que obtengo, se ha subido la ActionBar junto con el TextureView de fondo y ademas el teclado se encuentra entrecortado:
[image: Resultado que obtengo]